# Multi-user login through JMeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter

I need some clarification in the testing process, specifically when multiple users (100 Users) login to a web application through JMeter.

I can log in with a single valid user but if there are 100 users and 1 is a valid user and 99 are invalid users, the 99 users cannot log in.

The problem is creating 100 is a difficult process.

Now, is testing login as mentioned above the same as testing with 100 valid users?

If not, is there any better process to test login with multi-users?

Comment: Clarified the question without changing the meaning.

Comment: I want to test login in a web application with 100 users, I have 1 Valid user whos login will be is successful. Creating 100 valid users is difficult. Now the question is testing login with 1 valid & 99 invalids is the same as testing with 100 valid users or not. If not is there a better way to test it with 100 users

Answer (score 0):

There is only one obvious requirement: each JMeter thread (virtual user) should use different credentials, in other words JMeter user must represent real user using real browser as close as possible, otherwise your load testing will not make sense.

So ideally you should have 100 different credentials so each virtual user could use its own username/password combination and have its own [session](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager). It particularly matters when your test scenario assumes some [business processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management), i.e. one user starts workflow, another one approves, third one finishes, etc.

If each load test iteration assumes "clean" system you could consider automating user creation process via [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) where you can create the prerequisites (users, content, whatever). Ask around, it might be the case you can create the user using a single [REST API](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) or [Database](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) call, or it could be possible to import users from [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) or using a [shell command](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

As a last resort you can use single credentials with multiple JMeter virtual users, however in this case you may run into issues with your application so try avoiding [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations so your test would represent just browsing.